# Python Opencv. Возможно ли выводить онко веб камеры на веб странице? Для например добавления кнопок к этому окну

Tags: python, opencv, cv2

Нужно сделать программу (с кнопками) для отправления фото.
Но в opencv можно только описать нажатие клавиш. Можно ли как-то выводить форму камеры в веб страницу? Есть примеры?

Comment: да, возможно конечно

Comment: @Space Researcher Есть какой-нибудь примерчик как это сделать? 
Вообще не представляю как это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import cv2
import os

from datetime import datetime
# from ui_main_window import *

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class Thread1(QThread):
    changePixmap = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.cap1.set(3, 480)
        self.cap1.set(4, 640)
        self.cap1.set(5, 30)
        while True:
            ret1, image1 = self.cap1.read()
            if ret1:
                im1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                height1, width1, channel1 = im1.shape
                step1 = channel1 * width1
                qImg1 = QImage(im1.data, width1, height1, step1, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                self.changePixmap.emit(qImg1)




def stop(self):
    #        if self.active == False:
    self.out1.release()


class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(660, 520)
        #        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        #        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.control_bt = QPushButton('START')
        self.control_bt.clicked.connect(self.controlTimer)
        self.image_label = QLabel()

        self.saveTimer = QTimer()

        self.th1 = Thread1(self)
        self.th1.changePixmap.connect(self.setImage)
        self.th1.start()

        vlayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.image_label)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.control_bt)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QImage)
    def setImage(self, qImg1):
        self.image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qImg1))

    def controlTimer(self):
        if not self.saveTimer.isActive():
            # write video
            self.saveTimer.start()
            self.th2 = (self)
            self.th2.active = True  # +
            self.th2.start()
            #            self.active = True
            # update control_bt text
            self.control_bt.setText("STOP")
        else:
            # stop writing
            self.saveTimer.stop()
            #            self.active = False
            self.th2.active = False  # +

            self.th2.stop()  # +
            self.th2.terminate()  # +
            # update control_bt text
            self.control_bt.setText("START")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```